# Proof regarding logical equivalency and sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Statement to prove $$A∩B=A ≡A⊂B$$

Solution : Lets use abbreviations *LHS* and *RHS* for left and right sides of this equivalency. Lets first show that *LHS*→*RHS*. Lets assume that *LHS* is true. This means that.. $$(A∩B)⊂A$$$$A⊂(A∩B)$$

Lets write this as $$x∈(A∩B)→x∈A$$$$x∈A→x∈(A∩B)$$

This shows, that if x is an element of A it must also be an element of B, which means that A is a subset of B. Lets now show that *RHS*→*LHS* is true by contradicton. Assume *LHS* to be false. A is not a subset of B.. $$∃x∣x∈A→x∉B$$

Assume also, that *RHS* is true.$$∀x∣x∈(A∩B)→x∈A$$$$∀x∣x∈A→x∈(A∩B)$$ These assumptions contradict each other. Therefore *RHS*→*LHS* is always true. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I'm just looking for verification whether this is correct or not. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider here is the difference between $A \subset B$ and $A \subseteq B$. The former means that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, i.e. $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \wedge \exists y (y \in B \wedge y \not \in A)$. The latter means $A$ is a general subset, which is what I believe you mean by your proof, i.e. $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$. Essentially, $A \subseteq B$ leaves open the possibility that $A$ and $B$ could in fact be equal sets.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A \subset A$ and $A \cap B \subset A$ are always true, we have:

$$A \cap B = A$$

$$\overset{}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$${(A \cap B) \subset A}  \land A \subset (A \cap B)$$

$$\overset{}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$A \subset (A \cap B)$$

$$\overset{}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$A \subset A \land A \subset B$$

$$\overset{}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$A \subset B$$